# 2 fileds in a table associated to the same table

Tags: cakephp, associations

how can I display values from an over a JOIN table associated table in cakePHP?

I tried the following:

```
echo $post['Post']['user_id'] // displays e.g. '4'
```

but then I only get the id not the defined $displayfield of the user model.

It works when I use the association in an input field like:

```
echo $this->Form->input('user_id', array( 'label' => 'User'); // displays 'Mr. Oizo'
```

The virtualField is defined in the user model as follows:

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'VirtualName' => 'CONCAT(User.Name, " ", User.Vorname)'
    );

public $displayField = 'VirtualName';
```

Can anyone help me ?

Best regards
dan

Comment: You probably want [the containable behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the relationships defined between models correctly, you would display the User virtual field like this in your view:

```
echo $post['User']['VirtualName']
```